# Как взаимодействовать с командной строкой внутри python программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, командная-строка

Хочу написать программу для создания инсталяторов. Программа должна создавать код для инсталятора и паковать скрипт, который запросил пользователь и сам код инсталятора в exe. Но вот проблема - для того чтобы сделать вышеуказанное действие нужна работа с командной строкой(или окном администратора - как кому удобнее). Пакую в exe я с помощью библиотеки pyinstaller. Как сделать так, чтобы программа могла взаимодействовать с pyinstaller? Ведь для того чтобы ВООБЩЕ КАК-ТО взаимодействовать с pyinstaller нужно использовать командную строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте модуль [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Пример:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls", "-h"])
```